# Set/Add Background Image in PDF using Symfony Framework

Tags: php, pdf, symfony-1.4

I'm making an HTML PDF template and I'm about to set the background image.

Here's my code below:

```
<?php
class pdfAction extends sfAction{
  public function execute($request){
    $id = $request->getParameter('id');
    if(!$id){
      return $this->forward404();
    }
    $testTemplate = Doctrine_Core::getTable('PrintManual')->findOneById($id);
    if(!$testTemplate){
      return $this->forward404();
    }

    $config = sfTCPDFPluginConfigHandler::loadConfig('my_config');
    sfTCPDFPluginConfigHandler::includeLangFile($this->getUser()->getCulture());

    $pdf = new sfTCPDF();

    $pdf->SetTitle('Precena Biz - Test Template');
    $pdf->SetSubject('Precena Biz - Test Template');

    $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
    $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
    $content = myTools::loadTemplate('pdfTpl',array('test'=>$testTemplate), sfConfig::get('sf_root_dir') . '/apps/AdmSys/modules/test/templates');

    $pdf->AddPage();

    $pdf->SetFont('kochiminchosubst', "", 13);

    $pdf->writeHTML($content, true, 0);

    //$pdf->AddI();
    $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
    $pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

    $pdf->Output('test.pdf', 'I');

    throw new sfStopException();
    return $this->renderText('');
  }

}
```

How will I add or set the image into background ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use wkhtmltopdf
tool. https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

Comment: no need to add tool all i want is to set it as background image

Comment: how will i add to it ?